# Aggregate nested field in elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

```
GET /civile/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "annosentenza": "2020"
                }
              }
            ],
            "should": []
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "gradogiudizio": "2"
                }
              }
            ],
            "should": []
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [],
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "tipotesto"
                    }
                  },
                  "must": {
                    "match": {
                      "numerosentenza": "630"
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "tipotesto"
                    }
                  },
                  "must": {
                    "match": {
                      "numerosentenza": "1113"
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "tipotesto"
                    }
                  },
                  "must": {
                    "match": {
                      "numerosentenza": "770"
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "tipotesto"
                    }
                  },
                  "must": {
                    "match": {
                      "numerosentenza": "2234"
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "tipotesto"
                    }
                  },
                  "must": {
                    "match": {
                      "numerosentenza": "612"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "text": "risarcimento"
                }
              }
            ],
            "should": []
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "distretto": "MI"
                }
              }
            ],
            "should": []
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "tipotesto"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "text_annot_controparte",
                  "query": {
                    "match_phrase": {
                      "text_annot_controparte.value_string": "Unicredit spa"
                    }
                  },
                  "inner_hits": {}
                }
              }
            ],
            "should": []
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "text_annot_controparte_agg": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "text_annot_controparte"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "value_string_agg": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "text_annot_controparte.value_string.keyword"
          }
        },
        "aggs": {
           
            "bucket_selector": {
              "buckets_path": {
                "docCount": "value_string_agg._count"
              },
              "script": "params.docCount > 1"
            }
          
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I done an elasticsearch query where I want to aggregate a nested text_annot_controparte field.

```
"text_annot_controparte": [
            {
                "er_name": "metamodello1",
                "entity_type": "Persona",
                "search_default_type": "value_string",
                "value_string": "Unicredit spa",
                "value_numeric": null,
                "entity_id": 333333,
                "aid": 45,
                "value_date": null
            },
            {
                "er_name": "metamodello1",
                "entity_type": "Persona",
                "search_default_type": "value_string",
                "value_string": "Banca Agricola",
                "value_numeric": null,
                "entity_id": 333333,
                "aid": 45,
                "value_date": null
            }
        ]
```

I got this error:
"caused_by" : {
"type" : "class_cast_exception",
"reason" : "class org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.nested.InternalNested cannot be cast to class org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.InternalMultiBucketAggregation (org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.nested.InternalNested and org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.InternalMultiBucketAggregation are in unnamed module of loader 'app')"
}

It seems aggregation isn't permitted for nidified or nested field.
How can I solve it?